# How to customize namespace prefix in objects inheriting from lxml.ElementBase

Tags: python, lxml

From the lxml documentation, I understand that custom XML elements should inherit from `ElementBase`.

For instance, I can create

```
class FactVariable(etree.ElementBase):
    ''' Class that represents a XBRL fact variable.'''
    TAG = '{http://xbrl.org/2008/variable}factVariable'

    @property
    def label(self):
        return self.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}label']

    @label.setter
    def label(self, value):
        self.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}label'] = value
```

My problem is that when I create a XML tree and place such nodes, I get

```
<ns0:factVariable xmlns:ns0="http://xbrl.org/2008/variable" label="azerty"/>
```

**Question**: I want the namespace to be prefixed `va`, not `ns0` How can I change that?

I tried to set the `self.nsmap` property, but I have a "read-only" exception.
Adding a key/value has no effect (as said in the documentation).

I also tried, without success

```
etree.register_namespace('va', 'http://xbrl.org/2008/variable')
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old and probably @rds solved this, but I was encountering a similar problem, so thought I'd share som info.
It seems that setting the nsmap upon creation will at least work:

```
>>> etree.tostring(FactVariable(label='qwerty', nsmap={'va':'http://xbrl.org/2008/variable'}))
'<va:factVariable xmlns:va="http://xbrl.org/2008/variable" label="qwerty"/>'
```